# adding a jQuery effect only to the HTML element parent onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I want to apply the jquery effect 'flash' to "simpleCart_shelfItem", the parent of the html element "item_add". This is to indiacte that the user has added an item to the cart. I am doing it by referring to the parent as there are many "simpleCart_shelfItem" instances and I want the effect to only occur on the one that was clicked. I have been reading up on `this` and from what I gathered, I cant have the `onClick` event inline because `this` will be global and not refer to the element in the function. This is what I have:

Javascript

```
$(".item_add").onclick = highlight;

function highlight(){

  $(".item_add").parent().effect("highlight", {}, 750);
};
```

HTML

```
<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
                <div class="image"><img src="css/graphics/jpeg/saw.jpg" alt="Hacksaw" height="75" width="75" /></div>
                <h2 class="item_name">Hacksaw</h2>
                <span class="item"><img src="css/graphics/jpeg/cart.jpg" alt="Shopping Cart" height="20" width="19" />
            Items in Cart: <b class="simpleCart_quantity"></b></span> 
                <div class="description"><p>Quality metal hacksaw and 24 tooth blade.</p><p class="p_height">Your going to need some way of cutting that pipe. Good for the toolbox.</p></div>
                <a class="add_products" href="cart.html">Go to Cart</a>
                <a class="add_products" href="products.html" title="Add Items">Add More Items</a>
                <span class="gst">(Inc. GST)</span>
                <span class="item_price">$24.95</span>
                <input class="item_quantity" value="1" type="text">
                **<a href="javascript:;" class="item_add" onclick="highlight();">Add</a>**
            </div><!--end of simpleCart_shelfItem-->
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery already why not use jQuery's event binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".item_add").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().effect("highlight", {}, 750);
});
```

In the above example `this` refers to the element clicked. I don't know what you exactly mean by `this` is global, but you are wrong :-) (or I misunderstood you).

From http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html:

> In JavaScript this always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of.

Check out [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uCcYw/)

Comment: You might want to mention that 'this' is most certainly NOT global, and does indeed refer to each individual element when the click happens.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was reading this http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html but i think i misunderstood. Why isnt it working then??

Comment: That should just be `$('.item_add').click(...);` - `onclick()` isn't a jQuery function.

Comment: Thanks @anthony. ok i changed it to click but still no joy. Should it look like this: `$('.item_add').click = highlight;`

Comment: Also, with regard to the "this is global" in the question: If you assign an inline event handler (`onclick="foo()"`) then `this` inside of the function `foo` will refer to the window object. Take a look at [this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonygrist/syKGp/). I assume that's what was meant.

Comment: @user1292064 `.click()` is a jQuery function called on a jQuery object, not a property of a DOM element. Your code should be `$('.item_add').click(highlight);`.

Comment: @Anthony Grist, sorry yeah window is what I was referring to. I know that simplecart_shelfitem is the parent so it will work if I can get `this` to correctly refer to item_add.

Comment: @user1292064 why don't you just use an anonymous function as callback as in my answer?

Comment: @user1292064 I have added a demo check it out in my answer.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa, sorry i dont understand what you mean? checking demo now. thanks

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa, sorry i missed that. I looks great, i will give it a go now. Thankyou so much.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa, it works in jfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/uCcYw/3/) but not on my page [link](http://www.diysoakwells.com.au/accessories.html). What am I missing. Your example taught me a lot, thankyou.

Comment: I do get errors when trying to add something to cart: "Shelf item with id of s1 does not exist." Also you should just remove that inline JS stuff: "javascript:;".

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa, I saw the error too but it is part of the simpleCart script I am using. The effect worked when I was using inline onclick as a test.

Comment: inline javascript removed and cursor style added.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa, I dont think the error is relavant a sitems are being added to the cart:  `addToCart : function ( id ) {
  return function(){
   if( simpleCart.Shelf.items[id]){
    simpleCart.Shelf.items[id].addToCart();
   } else {
    error( "Shelf item with id of " + id + " does not exist.");
   }
  };
 }
};`